# CSS: Sidebar won't appear inside parent element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add two sidebars to both edges of the middle element. The left one works without an issue, however, the right one won't. Instead, it appears below its parent element (as seen in the picture) unless I position it as absolute, then however, it goes over the navbar.

Relevant css:

```
/* The parent element */
main {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 22%;
    right: 22%;
    width: 56%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

/* The correctly shown sidebar */
.sidenav {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    top: 7%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 7%;
}

/* The wrongly shown sidebar */
.bar-right{
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 7%;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <main>
    <div class="topbar">
      [top bar stuff]
    </div>
    <div class="sidenav">
      <a href="[url]" class="userheader">[usernamestuff]</a>
      <a href="[url]">Link1</a>
      <a href="[url]">Link2</a>
      <a href="[url]">Link3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-right">
      <p>text for test</p>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Both sidebars are effectively identical so I don't understand why they behave so differently. How do I get them both to their appropriate edges of the main element?

[image: website]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). This will help you to achieve what you looking for so easy, by this code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
      // First sidebar
      </div>
      <div class="col-offset-6 col-sm-3">
      // Second sidebar
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I might try that out later, for now, though, I would like to figure this out using css only as that would teach me to better understand how css works and what I did wrong.